# cron job script creating unwanted files

Tags: scripting, cron, jobs

I have a cron job script and i used >/dev/null 2>&1 to Stop sending Emails. But each time a file is created in the same name of PHP file with trailing numbers like phpfile.php.1, phpfle.php.2, phpfile.php.3….
Is there any script to stop that?

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-O /dev/null` to your `wget` command.